# Typesafe solution for using map and spread operator

Tags: typescript

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?
I have an interface, say IFoo, and an array of data IFoo[]. I want to map these data and change a single property. Something like this

```
const mapper = (foos: IFoo[]): IFoo[] => {
  return foos.map((f) => {
    return {
      ...f,
      prop4: 42
    };
  });
};
```

The problem is that "prop4" does not exists in IFoo, but the compiler is happy, because I have used the spread operator "...f" and therefor all required props are set. But I meant to change "prop3" and doesn't see and doesn't get a compiler error.

Explict setting all properties is not a good solution, because it's tedious and if a new prop which can be undefined is added to IFoo one must remember to update this function.

You can see the complete example at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/typesafe-interface-eqhvy?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be perhaps explicitly stating the type of the merged object, so that it must be `IFoo`: then, TypeScript will know that the object can only contain properties listed in the `IFoo` interface, and warn you if that's not the case:

```
const mapper = (foos: IFoo[]): IFoo[] => {
  return foos.map((f) => {
    const foo: IFoo = {
      ...f,
      prop4: 42 // Error: 'prop4' does not exist in type 'IFoo'
    };

    return foo;
  });
};
```

See [proof-of-concept on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyyADlJsQIwBcyIArgLYBG0A3ISWcQEw33NsOpcgGY+jFlHYBffPgSYQAZzDIGcYsWgVkAXmQAKGNiU0M2ANoBdAJRmsma3oB8eDlAhg6UEMmOYlADp1YgMjGxc3IiIFZVV-e2w9KOiiQPSYABoOVOFiABYafO5kAHpS5ABRKDIoHORpdnqPLx8-bHYiaRsZJtiVNQ0tKBL9IxNEx1tJp11XAiIW719-IJCwmAi5lJjFAYS0B2SF1OR0wKz6ojyxZGKyioBBAFpMAGt6xrlUpbb-ToaPXwjSAA).